# Show the foreign key id's that occur more than n times

Tags: sql, group-by, count, mariadb, having-clause

[mariaDB]

Hi, I need to show the foreign key ids from another table that occur more than 4 times in my primary table.

for example: 5 persons have a foreign key id from my secondary table of 001, 6 persons have a foreign key id of 002, and 3 persons have a foreign key id of 003.

Now I need to output the foreign key ID's that have more than 4 persons, in this example that would be 001 and 002.

Thanks and sorry if unclear, kinda hard to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for aggregation. Assuming that your foreign key column is called `fk`, you would do:

```
select fk, count(*) no_persons
from mytable
group by fk
having count(*) > 4
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this

```
SELECT key, count(*) from table GROUP BY key HAVING count(*) > 4 ORDER BY key asc
```

if you need ordering etc.